# Mongoose ignores string attributes in post requests

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, curl, mongoose

I am currently developing a RESTful API with Express using TypeScript and MongoDB. My ORM of choice is mongoose. When test my Application with the following POST request:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "first_name":"hansi"}' localhost:3000
```

I get the following error message, stating that the attribute "first_name" is required:

```
{ ValidationError: Person validation failed: first_name: Enter a first name
    at ValidationError.inspect (/Users/schnabl/s6/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/validation.js:59:24)
    at formatValue (internal/util/inspect.js:453:31)
    at inspect (internal/util/inspect.js:193:10)
    at Object.formatWithOptions (util.js:85:12)
    at Console.(anonymous function) (console.js:188:15)
    at Console.log (console.js:199:31)
    at /Users/schnabl/s6/src/routes/person.js:23:29
    at /Users/schnabl/s6/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4533:16
    at parallel (/Users/schnabl/s6/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:2667:16)
    at /Users/schnabl/s6/node_modules/async/internal/parallel.js:39:9
    at /Users/schnabl/s6/node_modules/async/internal/once.js:12:16
    at iteratorCallback (/Users/schnabl/s6/node_modules/async/eachOf.js:60:13)
    at /Users/schnabl/s6/node_modules/async/internal/onlyOnce.js:12:16
    at /Users/schnabl/s6/node_modules/async/internal/parallel.js:36:13
    at callbackWrapper (/Users/schnabl/s6/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:2640:20)
    at /Users/schnabl/s6/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4533:16
  errors:
   { first_name:
      { ValidatorError: Enter a first name
          at new ValidatorError (/Users/schnabl/s6/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/validator.js:29:11)
          at validate (/Users/schnabl/s6/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:871:13)
          at /Users/schnabl/s6/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:924:11
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
          at SchemaString.SchemaType.doValidate (/Users/schnabl/s6/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:880:19)
          at /Users/schnabl/s6/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1913:9
          at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
        message: 'Enter a first name',
        name: 'ValidatorError',
        properties: [Object],
        kind: 'required',
        path: 'first_name',
        value: undefined,
        reason: undefined,
        [Symbol(mongoose:validatorError)]: true } },
  _message: 'Person validation failed',
  name: 'ValidationError' }
```

However, when I comment the '"required: "enter a string"' out, no server error is thrown. But still the first_name and all the other string attributes I use in my schema aren't added to the collection. There are just the Mongo generated "ids" and default values for the birth_date (current_timestamp) in the collection.

My schema (personSchema.ts):

```
//imports

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

export const PersonSchema = new Schema({
    first_name: {
        type: String
        //required: "Enter a first name"
    },
    ...
    birth_date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    } 
}, { collection: 'person' });
```

The router (personRouter.ts):

```
//imports

export class PersonRoute {
    public personController: PersonController = new PersonController();

    public routes(app): void {
      ...
      //getrequests
      ...

      app.route("/").post((req: Request, res: Response) => {

        const PersonModel = mongoose.model('Person', PersonSchema);

        PersonModel.create(req.body, function (err, post) {
          if (err) console.log(err);
          res.json(post);
        });
      });
    }
}
```

Is it possible that there is something wrong with my test request?

EDIT:
I tested the post request in Postman and still getting the same result:

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at what `req.body` actually contains?

Comment: I can't exactly relate to your question - which requests body do you mean?

Comment: You're doing `PersonModel.create(req.body, ...)`. What does `req.body` contain? Have you tried `console.log(req.body)` to check its contents?

Comment: req.body aswell as res.body are undefined, but req itself is not

Comment: It seems as it is a bug with the express body parser and/or my configuration of it

Comment: I'm going to suggest the latter. Make sure that you use it _before_ any of your routes/routers. `req.body` being undefined means that the `body-parser` middleware hasn't gotten a chance to handle the request at all.

Comment: Reinstalling express body parsers helped -thanks for your help

Comment: set a log into your endpoint, see what's coming into request body.